# Ubuntu 13.04 on 2013 15" Macbook Pro Retina Display with Apple 27" Thunderbolt Display

Tags: 13.04, apple, thunderbolt

I know that people have managed to get the MBP-retine working with ubuntu 13.04, but has anyone been successful in getting to drive a thunderbolt display? Or is the LED cinema display the only option?

Answer (score 1):

was looking to get this thunderbolt display to work for a long time. couldn't get it to work. Will sound absurd, however I went to passwords and keys, removed the Login key (capital L) and created a new one called 'login' (small l).
Now everything (thunderbolt display included) works like a charm... hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have a MacBook Pro Retina 15" and a Thunderbolt display. I have Ubuntu 13.04 installed and haven't had a single issue using the display. It works like a charm.

I did notice that the laptop display wasn't automatically turning off when operating in clamshell mode, so I manually disabled it in the display settings.